# Delete lines between two patterns excluding the other lines containing these pattern

Tags: awk

I would want to only remove the lines between PATTERN1(aaa) and PATTERN2(ccc), excluding the others lines where the patterns matches.

I trying to delete the empty line between PATTERN1(aaa) and PATTERN2(ccc), line 8 in my example...This line will be no all times in same location, that is the reason, why I try to remove it using the 2 patterns.

Essentially it boils down to: "If a blank line is found between aaa and ccc then remove it...

**input file**

```
aaa 409
bbb 201

122 0.98
aaa 1.47
aaa 0.00
aaa 0.00

ccc 0.00
121 0.01
135 1.99
```

**output file**

```
aaa 409
bbb 201

122 0.98
aaa 1.47
aaa 0.00
aaa 0.00
ccc 0.00
121 0.01
135 1.99
```

**attempts**

```
sed  '/aaa/,/ccc/{//p;d;}' file
sed '/aaa/,/ccc/{//!d}' file
awk '/aaa/{g=1;next}/ccc/{g=0;next}g' file
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to says what you want to do in another way, so someone as stupid as /me can understand what you want to do .... 

Comment: Sorry but this is not looking like you are deleting lines, you are inserting lines here,please edit your samples and let us know then.

Comment: You already know sed isnt the right tool for this and you got answers to dozens of similar questions using awk so why even post sed attempts.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I trying to delete the empty line between PATTERN1(aaa) and PATTERN2(ccc), line 8 in my example...This line will be no all times in same location, that is the reason, why I try to remove it using the 2 patterns.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sed works but delete all lines which contended same pattern?.. I want to remove only the line between these 2 patterns.

Comment: @OXXO, ok if you want to fill empty lines then why 3rd line is NOT filled, kindly elaborate more in your question and let us know then.

Comment: It's unclear why you do not want to remove the 3rd line. Is is also between `aaa` and `ccc`, and is also empty ?

Comment: 3rd line is between 2 patterns - `aaa` is on  the 1st line and `ccc` is on the 9th line. So 3rd line is between `aaa` and `ccc`.

Comment: @Luuk, i don't want to remove empty lines?. I want to remove the line between the 2 patterns only .

Comment: But line 1 is using patter `aaa` and line 9 is using pattern `ccc`, and line 3 is an empty line......

Comment: @Luuk, that's why I mentioned... excluding the other lines which contends the same patterns.

Comment: This is a tricky one. Essentially it boils down to:  *"If a blank line is found between `aaa` and `ccc` then remove it. Do not remove blank lines between patterns `aaa` and `aaa`"*

Comment: `excluding the other lines`, which is, in my understanding, excluding lines before line#1 and after line 9.....

Comment: @Luuk, patterns /aaa/and/ccc/ will not all time at same position, then, I can give you line numbers... ?

Comment: `Sed works but ...` = `Sed doesn't work`. Even if you could come up with some arcane set of runes to make some version of sed spit out the output you want for some specific set of input you have, it's simply not the right tool for the job. You've seen dozens of awk answers to your previous questions, you shouldn't even be considering sed for this.

Comment: @EdMorton, I tried all I can to get awk works on this but i don't find a solution. awk '/aaa/{g=1;next}/ccc/{g=0;next}g' ..

Comment: `gawk '/aaa/{ x=1;}/ccc/{ x=x-1; }{ print NR, x, $0 }' oxxo`   shows that there is NO difference (take note of the description OXXO gave) between line 3 and line 8. This is simply a BAD asked question!

Comment: My point is simply this: if your problem requires a solution that's a simple s/old/new on an individual string then definitely consider using sed but if it's not then don't waste your time trying to cludge something together with sed when an awk solution will always be some combination of clearer, simpler, more portable, more robust, more efficient, and easier to maintain - usually all of them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/aaa/ { printf "%s", block; block=""; inBlock=1 }
!inBlock { print }
inBlock {
    block = block $0 ORS
    if ( /ccc/ ) {
        gsub(/\n+/,"\n",block)
        printf "%s", block
        block = ""
        inBlock = 0
    }
}
END { printf "%s", block }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaa 409
bbb 201

122 0.98
aaa 1.47
aaa 0.00
aaa 0.00
ccc 0.00
121 0.01
135 1.99
```

The above removes all blank lines in  the block of lines between `ccc` and the closest `aaa` before it. To isolate that block it starts the block when it sees an `aaa` and then restarts it (after printing what was stored as-is) if/when the next `aaa` is encountered before a `ccc` is encountered.

Comment: Ed Morton, Thank you, maestro, code works perfectly. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you again.